# How to show the all products by using REST API in magento1.9?

Tags: magento-1.9, rest-api

How to show the all products by using REST API in magento1.9?

Comment: Hi, if my answer solves your concern then please mark as right, which will help future readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**How to List Products to Android Based Application using REST API**

*____________________________________________________________________*

**REST Resources**

*The Magento REST API allows you to manage customers, customer addresses, sales orders, inventory, and products. REST API is organized into the following categories*

> Products

- Retrieve the list of products, create, update, and delete a product.

**Resource Structure**: http://magentohost/api/rest/products

**Additional Information**

> You can define the limit of items returned in the response by passing
>   the limit parameter. By default, 10 items are returned and the maximum
>   number is 100 items. You can also define the page number by passing
>   the page parameter.

**Example**:

```
http://magentohost/api/rest/products?page=2&limit=20
```

Authorization header will be required for Admin and Customer user types. The following parameters must be provided in the Authorization header for the call

```
oauth_consumer_key - the Consumer Key value provided after the registration of the application.
oauth_nonce - a random value, uniquely generated by the application.
oauth_signature_method - name of the signature method used to sign the request. Can have one of the following values: HMAC-SHA1, RSA-SHA1, and PLAINTEXT.
oauth_signature - a generated value (signature).
oauth_timestamp - a positive integer, expressed in the number of seconds since January 1, 1970 00:00:00 GMT.
oauth_token - the oauth_token value (Request Token).
oauth_version - OAuth version.
```

> Note : DOCS welcome

Swagger is only available in **Magento 2.x** But, for Magento 1.x You can check on **[devdocs](https://devdocs.magento.com/swagger/)** site also there is title mentioned that "Magento Commerce for B2B
"

You can refer the below links:

> For Magento Open Source 1.5 to 1.9

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/rest/introduction.html

**Magento devdocs** provides all basic **REST API** for the **Magento 1.x** and it is **Authentic** source

you can develop it from here **from scratch**

> For Magento 1.x API documentation,

1. [Magento 1.x SOAP API](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/soap/introduction.html)
2. [Magento 1.x REST API](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/rest-api-index.html)